# Achieve result like Google Play Store's "list inside list"

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I want to be able to achieve the same result as Google in their play store app.

[image]

The only way i could think of was to add a Recyclerview in a Recyclerview adapter like below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The inside view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="100dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is the inside Recyclerview won't display correctly.

[image]

Do you know how to make it show its content or do you have any idea how to achieve it another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google uses a list inside another list : the inner one is not scrollable so... They just build a cell with multiple rows if needed (i.e. if the data contains multiple payment methods) in the recycler adapter.

You can actually see "more payment settings", so I guess this card has a fixed max number of payment methods to display.

Comment: It seems they do. I just erased my credit card number on the screenshot but they add all the payments methods one after the other on the top, above the "add a payment method" element.

Comment: That does not mean they use a listview. Once again there is no scrolling involved

Comment: I understand but how could they achieve it then ? Adding views manually in a LinearLayout ? The animation really looks like a recyclerview animation to me. You can check it out by yourself if you want to see.

Comment: That's how I do it. See this layout : http://postimg.org/image/o5vr58fjr/1905a0ed/  
It is a list into a view pager into a listview.
No matter how much requirements exist, I'll show only the four first ones